# Dynamic form control in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder

I am creating a screen using Angular 2. It contains two radio buttons A and B. On the check of "A" I need to display the dropdown control and on the check of "B" it should display text box instead of the dropdown. I followed [this](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/) blog and modified my code according to it.
Now everything works as expected but when I try to build with prod flag it gives me below error:
**Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'**
On the change of the radio button, I am adding and removing controls.

```
  handleChange(evt) {
    this.items = this.importExp.get('items') as FormArray;
    if (evt === this.database) {
      this.selectedApproach = this.database;
      this.delInput(0);
      this.items.push(this.createDbItem());
    } else {
      this.selectedApproach = this.file;
      this.delInput(0);
      this.items.push(this.createFileItem());
    }
  }

  delInput(index: number): void {
    const arrayControl = <FormArray>this.importExp.controls['items'];
    arrayControl.removeAt(index);
  }

  createForm() {
    this.importExp = this.fb.group({
      importFromDb: ['database'],
      items: this.fb.array([this.createDbItem()])
    });
  }

  createDbItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      dbServer: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  createFileItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      fileTxt: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
```

on the html side

```
  <div formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of importExp.controls['items'].controls; let i = index;">
                <div [formGroupName]="i">
                  <div *ngIf="this.selectedApproach == this.database" class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" for="dbServerID">Exposure Server</label>
                    <div>
                      <select formControlName="dbServer" class="form-control custom-select" id="dbServerId" (ngModelChange)="onSelectServer($event)">
                        <option *ngFor="let ds of databaseServers" [ngValue]="ds">
                          {{ds.databaseServerName}}
                        </option>
                      </select>
                      <span class="fa fa-search-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <!-- <app-control-message ErrorMsg="Database Name" [control]="dbServer"></app-control-message> -->
                    </div>
```

And i am getting error in 1 line of HTML on build. I have tried other approaches also

```
<div *ngFor="let item of importExp.controls.items.controls; let i=index">
```

but it's not working.

Comment: After a lot of searches, I finally got the solution here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6099